# Fragment is too slow when change on bottomnavigatioview?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

My Fragment is taking so much time in update layout It is because of a lot of code in fragment how to resolve this please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyttabs"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <com.bugfree.caviar.fonts.BabesNeueProBold
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="My Events That I am..."
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
                android:src="@drawable/plus"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/button_red_back"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_indicator_color"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lytCreateEvent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".activity.CreateEvent">



            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgBack"
                android:src="@drawable/back_black"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />



        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                    <com.bugfree.caviar.fonts.BabesNeueProBold
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Create event"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="30dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.bugfree.caviar.fonts.BabesNeueProBoldRegular
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Event title" />

                    <EditText
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:paddingStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_back"
                        android:id="@+id/edtEventTitle"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:hint="Beach Yoga!"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <com.bugfree.caviar.fonts.BabesNeueProBoldRegular
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Event type" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_back"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <com.bugfree.caviar.fonts.BabesNeueProBoldRegular
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:paddingStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Business"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="12dp"
                        android:layout_height="12dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <com.bugfree.caviar.fonts.BabesNeueProBoldRegular
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Event description" />

                    <com.bugfree.caviar.fonts.BabesNeueProBoldRegular
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:text="94/300" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custombutton_border_edittext"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:id="@+id/edtDescription"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/black_text_new"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:hint="Beach yoga with Alissia is a lifestyle focused on health,
                         wellness, and self-care through the practice of"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                 
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:tint="@color/black"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/down_arrowsmall"
                            android:layout_width="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="10dp" />


                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <EditText
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:id="@+id/edtSplReq"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/lay_without_border"
                        android:hint="Add a special request[optional]"
                        android:textColorHint="#848484"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />


                    <Button
                        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
                        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:text="Submit"
                        android:textColor="@color/space_white"
                        android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lytTab"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_indicator_color"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/button_red_back"
                    android:id="@+id/tabsLOc"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="fixed" />

                <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerLoc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my fragment

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {
private View view;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
LocationPagerAdapter locationPagerAdapter;
private String current = "";
private String ddmmyyyy = "MMDDYYYY";
private Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
FragmentEventBinding binding;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
public EventFragment() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Bebas Neue Pro Regular.otf");



    binding.lytTopImg.setOnClickListener(v -> {
       binding.lytLocDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.lytPartLocNew.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    });


    binding.imgTopEvent.setImageBitmap(SetBrightness(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dummy),-70));

    binding.imgBackLocDetail.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        binding.lytLocDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        binding.lytPartLocNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       /* Intent intent = new Intent(PartnerLocationActivity.this, LoactionDetails.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/
    });
    binding.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        binding.lyttabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        binding.lytCreateEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    });
    binding.imgBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mListener.changeFragment(2);

        binding.lyttabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.lytCreateEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    });

    binding.buttonCreateEvent.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        binding.lyttabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.lytCreateEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    });
    binding.imgBackPartnerLoc.setOnClickListener(v -> {


        binding.lytPartLocNew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        binding.lytCreateEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

       /* Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateEvent.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/
    });
    binding.lytTopPartLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            binding.lytLocDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            binding.lytPartLocNew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    binding.buttonCreateEvent.setTypeface(font);
    binding.edtEventTitle.setTypeface(font);
    binding.edtDescription.setTypeface(font);
    binding.edtNameLoc.setTypeface(font);
    binding.edtAddressLoc.setTypeface(font);
    binding.rdbOne.setTypeface(font);
    binding.rdbGroup.setTypeface(font);
    binding.buttonPartnerloc.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        binding.lytPartLocNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.lytCreateEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       /* Intent intent = new Intent(CreateEvent.this, PartnerLocationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/
    });
    binding.buttonCreateEvent.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        binding.lyttabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.lytCreateEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    });

    binding.edtDob.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                String clean = s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]|\\.", "");
                String cleanC = current.replaceAll("[^\\d.]|\\.", "");

                int cl = clean.length();
                int sel = cl;
                for (int i = 2; i <= cl && i < 6; i += 2) {
                    sel++;
                }

                if (clean.equals(cleanC)) sel--;

                if (clean.length() < 8) {
                    clean = clean + ddmmyyyy.substring(clean.length());
                } else {

                    int day = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(0, 2));
                    int mon = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(2, 4));
                    int year = Integer.parseInt(clean.substring(4, 8));

                    mon = mon < 1 ? 1 : mon > 12 ? 12 : mon;
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon - 1);
                    year = (year < 1900) ? 1900 : (year > 2100) ? 2100 : year;
                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

                    day = (day > cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE)) ? cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE) : day;
                    clean = String.format("%02d%02d%02d", day, mon, year);
                }

                clean = String.format("%s/%s/%s", clean.substring(0, 2),
                        clean.substring(2, 4),
                        clean.substring(4, 8));

                sel = sel < 0 ? 0 : sel;
                current = clean;
                binding.edtDob.setText(current);
                binding.edtDob.setSelection(sel < current.length() ? sel : current.length());

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {


            }catch (Exception ignored){

            }
        }
    }).start();

    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    binding.viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    binding.tabs.setupWithViewPager( binding.viewPager);

    /*binding.imgBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        binding.lytLocDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        binding.lytPartLocNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    });*/
    locationPagerAdapter = new LocationPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    binding.viewPagerLoc.setAdapter(locationPagerAdapter);
    binding.tabsLOc.setupWithViewPager(binding.viewPagerLoc);

    binding.edtSplReq.setTypeface(font);
    binding.edtEmail.setTypeface(font);
    binding.edtPhone.setTypeface(font);
    binding.edtLastName.setTypeface(font);
    binding.edtFirstname.setTypeface(font);
    binding.btnSubmit.setTypeface(font);
    binding.btnFindTable.setTypeface(font);
    binding.btnFindTable.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        binding.lytBtnFind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        binding.lytTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        binding.lytBookTable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    });
    binding.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            binding.lyttabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            binding.lytLocDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            binding.lytPartLocNew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            binding.lytCreateEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            binding.lytBookTable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            binding.lytBtnFind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            binding.lytTab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            binding.tabs.getSelectedTabPosition();
        }
    });
    return view =  binding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;

}

public Bitmap SetBrightness(Bitmap src, int value) {
    // original image size
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    // create output bitmap
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
    // color information
    int A, R, G, B;
    int pixel;

    // scan through all pixels
    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            // get pixel color
            pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            R = Color.red(pixel);
            G = Color.green(pixel);
            B = Color.blue(pixel);

            // increase/decrease each channel
            R += value;
            if(R > 255) { R = 255; }
            else if(R < 0) { R = 0; }

            G += value;
            if(G > 255) { G = 255; }
            else if(G < 0) { G = 0; }

            B += value;
            if(B > 255) { B = 255; }
            else if(B < 0) { B = 0; }

            bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }

    // return final image
    return bmOut;
}
}
```

Comment: Fragment is taking so much time in load XML tablayout and viewpagertt inside it

Comment: I have around 2000 lines of code in XML bc of character limit I could not mention all in StackOverflow

Comment: You are doing a lot of things in `onCreateView()`. Just inflate the view in `onCreateView()` and try to do other stuffs in `onViewCreated()`. May be it will help.

Comment: ok I would try this

Comment: It is not working the same as before

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this answer.

1. As per https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies

> Android Layouts allow you to nest UI objects in the view hierarchy. This nesting can also impose a layout cost.

Your layout has multiple levels of nesting, this can have a large cost to layout.
Simplifying you layout with a more flexible layout like a `ConstraintLayout` Might reduce the layout cost.

2. Sometimes you are just trying to do too much when creating a view, do some of the work in a background thread and update the view when done (optionally putting up a busy type of progress bar while doing it)

Some idea's based on your code shown.

Instead of scanning every pixel of an image with the `SetBrightness` method which could take some time depending on the size of the image.
Add the image to the layout without the Brightness adjusted, start background task adjust image Brightness and when done replace the original un-adjusted image with the adjusted image.
This could probably be done without a busy progress bar.

Delay the creation of the offscreen viewpager pages until they are really needed.
Instead of each Fragment in the viewpager creating it's view in `onCreateView` when the Viewpager is created, create a placeholder view in the Fragment's `onCreateView` and update it in the Fragment's `onResume` which is only called when the Fragment is shown on screen (note need a recent'ish version of Viewpager for this behaviour)